# Stop hacker via .bashrc

Tags: linux

On the /root/.bashrc I have a line that sends me an email with the IP every time somebody with the root user log in. It works fine

The problem is that the server is very old and it have very old software and I detect somebody access with root but not via password, must be some exploit

How I know? We change many times root password and when I got the email about the access, it has no logged IP in it

The question is: If I detect no IP, how can I kill that connection?

This is the line that gives me the IP and sents an email:

```
echo 'Root access on:' `date` `who` | mail -s "Root access from
`who | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1`" some_email@outlook.com
```

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Super User. Is disabling the root login via password not on option? Also, it is recommended to use ssh keys instead of passwords.

Comment: Does `finger root` show you any information about how the root users is connected or logged in?

Comment: ssh keys are one way that someone can continue to access despite password changes. Check `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work as well as you think. Put very simply - capturing logins via `.bashrc` is never going to be exhaustive, and as such it's not particularly valuable.

The core question is - why are you permitting root logins in the first place? That's always an area of risk, simply because it's one account to compromise, and a known username to attack.

Far better to instead deny all root logins, and require users to use `sudo` to escalate privilege. That way the sudo audit log will capture the *user* who did it, and then you don't need to worry about the IP address.

Or look in the ssh log, and see who's logging in from where, because that should be able to capture login attempts.

Relying on a file in userspace is a poor quality security precaution.

Edit: You indicate in your comments that you think your server has been compromised. I would therefore you suggest looking at: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: There is no other users on the server, I mean, just root and admin but I know nobody knows the passwords. I think the hacker enter via some apache exploit

Comment: In which case - your system is compromised and you need to rebuild. Sorry, there's just no other way. http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with this check:

- Anyone logging in locally won't have any IP address
- Anyone using `su` won't be shown in `who`
- Anyone accessing the machine over SSH without using interactive shell (`ssh root@server whoami`) won't trigger this check
- `who` reports all active sessions

Stop using password for root account and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply

- In this server nobody can logging locally
- For su command, doesn't it need the password? Else how can I prevent this?
- Nobody can access via ssh but me. Nobody has the password
- There are no active session because nobody enters the server

I think the hacker uses root because some apache exploit or something

Comment: `su` needs the same password as SSH so if someone gets the SSH password, he can also use `su` (and vice versa). Apache should not be running under root so a hacker that takes control of it won't have root access.

Comment: I discover some files inside /tmp and with cat an nano saw inside. Those are scan IP ranges. It connects and auto update a list of IP's. The thing is that those file have apache owner

Comment: And they are run under Apache's user. The hacker does not have access to your root account (he doesn't need one) and so won't trigger your check.